# Detect time lapse between two key press in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and at the same time trying to create a simple script that allows you to type a foreign language on a web browser with your keyboard.

So, when you type `a` for example, there is a single letter mapped to a, so a single character `Դ` would appear, however to make a character like `厄` appear, you have to type twice, since this language has more characters than the English alphabet.

So, the problem is with that last character. Normally, I should have to type `g` and `h` consecutively in the span of **one second** to produce the `厄` letter, but I have problems waiting to check if within two characters have been typed within one second of eachother inorder to show that letter.

So, I don't think time interval functions are the way to go about this, but I can't see any other method also.

Comment: Store the last pressed time and measure the difference between it and now for every subsequent key pressed.

Comment: Have them hold down another key such as CTRL when two characters need to be typed consecutively

Comment: @alex I think that's a good idea, I don't know if I can divide the timing a get the response I need. It could come up as a float and would be hard to know which is a two-key-press letter or not

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Yeah, that would work if there were few of those two-key-press letter, unfortunatelly, they are like ~50 so it would be cumbersome to use it

Comment: Yes but measuring the time between key-presses is guesswork.  Better cumbersome and precise in my opinion

Comment: It surely isnt that cumbersome to hold ctrl, it's just like using shift for a capital letter at the end of the day.  The only real drawback of that method is that it won't work for mobile keyboards.  But a second per key press is a very long time, that'd seriously hinder people's typing speed.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing it this was is going to mean that when you don't want to type a two-keypress character, you have to pause a second between keypresses. That's going to slow your typing down a lot. I think that in practice, you'll find typing this way very frustrating.

Comment: I said it would be cumbersome, because it has 50 alphabets that need multiple keys to be pressed. These are not rare or less-used words like uppercasing, but more like vowels and consonants. If you were to write a 100 letter sentences, that means you would have to press shift between 40 - 60 of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another answer about your question,perhaps this is your truly answer.

```js
 function duration(timestamps) {
        var last = timestamps.pop();
        var durations = [];
        while (timestamps.length) {
            durations.push(last - (last = timestamps.pop()));
        }
        return durations.reverse();
    }

    function display(mills) {
        if (mills > 1000)
            return (mills / 1000) + ' s';
        return mills + ' ms';
    }

    var durations = [];

    $('#in').keydown(function (e) {
        durations.push($.now());
    }).keyup(function (e) {
        var current = durations;
        current.push($.now());
        durations = [];
        var timeElapsed = current[current.length - 1] - current[0];

        console.log([
            ['time elapsed:', display(timeElapsed)].join(' '),
            ['keys duration:', duration(current).map(display)].join(' ')
        ].join(' --- '));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <h2>Please input something to test!</h2>
    <input id="in"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this might do it. I will recreate it in pure js, since I want to learn js on the way, but thanks

Answer (score 3):

cautions: check key whether up in keydown() & notify keydown the key is upped in keypress();

```js
   var start = null;
    $('#in').keydown(function (e) {
        if (!start) {//checking is a new user input
            start = $.now();
        }
    }).keyup(function (e) {
        var timeElapsed = $.now() - start;
        start = null;//start the next  timing tracking
         
         console.log(['time elapsed:', timeElapsed, 'ms'].join(' '));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<h2>please input some letter to test</h2>
<input id="in"/>
</label>
```

Comment: hmm, thanks. this actually is what I was looking for, but for some reason I don't get the time difference between just two keys, but all keys. It seems the script does not know which letter is satisfied with one press, to forget about it. But I should have provided more info ... anyway, I will check and update later

Comment: can't get the keychars that I have test because this processed by system input method.^_^,I from china.`呃` is not `a`,is `e`.

Comment: Yeah, that character is just for example. I will check it tonight and update

Comment: to detect duration in each key you can use an `array` not the `start` long instead,then you can implement it.note:see my caution in the answer, this is the important.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code to measure the elapsed time between any 2 events.
I added `setTimeout` just to give you an example.

```js
var startTime = Date.now();

setTimeout(function(){
 var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
 console.log('elapsedTime ='+elapsedTime);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to wrap this inside event listener?

Comment: Remember that `now()` is `static` method of `Date`. And it acts similar to what you get from calling `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Yes. You can wrap it, you need to provide some sample code that you tried so that we can provide more pointers.

Comment: `underscore.js` library has `_.debounce` function. Check if you can use it to solve your problem.

Comment: hmm, thanks .. but not even sure what debounce means ... I think I will go vanillajs with this one, it is good for learning too

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex mentioned, for every press, simply store `new Date().getTime();` in a variable, which will get you the latest UTC time. UTC time is given in milliseconds, so on the next key-press, just see if the current time and the stored time differ by 1000!

Comment: This is nice, thanks I will try it and through trial and error, hope something comes up. I just need to know onething, do I have to invoke the `new Date()` object on each `onkey` event, or is there a way to store it somehow. I would assume invoking it everytime may be CPU-extensive